# Firebase Cocoa Pods Error After Swift 5 Update

Tags: swift, xcode, firebase, cocoapods, swift5

I am currently using Xcode Version 10.2 beta 4 and have updated the project to Swift 5. 
Upon doing this I have run into a ton of errors relating to my Firebase Pods. [image: Screenshot of the errors]
I have deintegrated the pods and installed again and even tried pod update. I have also restarted Xcode multiple times and couldn't get these errors to clean themselves up.

Does anyone know what is happening here?

Comment: I see no error. They are warnings and it's a normal case while you're trying to use the beta version of a programming language. The Firebase does not support Swift 5 yet as I know.

Comment: @OnurTuna So I can just ignore these warnings and eventually Firebase will become supported in Swift 5 and then I'd just run like pod update?

Comment: Of course you should ignore. Things will change too much by the release of the stable Swift 5. Google will take action on it after a while.

Comment: @OnurTuna Alright, thank you for clarifying this.

Comment: More discussion about this at https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/issues/3218

Comment: I've read this is partially a clang issue https://openradar.appspot.com/radar?id=6091887509241856

Comment: I'm seeing this issue in my Firebase, Swift project too

Comment: @BradThomas As Onur said, you can just ignore the warnings. Everything for me still worked so I just ignored them.

Comment: I see same warnings too in my project

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Pods, put `inhibit_all_warnings!` in your Podfile and run `pod install` to silence the warnings.

Answer (score -1):

I have this issue too but with the official version of xCode 10.2.  Maybe as these are only warnings it isn’t blocking anything but it is slowing up my compiler, causing other errors